# Python 3.4 support has been deprecated, not able to install python modules, using pip command

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am using Python 3.4 and pip 10.0.1. I was getting error while running generated executable file for a Tkinter project using pyinstaller

The error I got while executing Mytool.exe file is:

```
MKL FATAL EOOR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll
```

I have gone through some suggestions from online forum, there I got some solution to how tofix pyinstaller error.
I was upgrading `numpy` and `intel_mkl` to latest version (`numpy-1.15.4+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`).

I have used the command:

```
pip install C:\Users\PRADEEP\Downloads\numpy-1.15.4+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

I got following error.

```
numpy-1.15.4+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I have upgraded pip using the command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Now have have latest version of pip: 19.1.1

When I tried same again with latest version of pip i got following error:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 3.4 support has been deprecated. pip 19.1 will be the last one supporting it. Please upgrade your Python as Python 3.4 won't be maintained after March 2019 (cf PEP 429).

ERROR: numpy-1.15.4+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`m
```

I got to know from the above procedure that, somewhere the packages (e.g. pip) are not supporting Python 3.4.

I want to successfully create an executable file for my Python Tkinter project.

Comment: You are seeing two *separate* things here: 1. Versions of pip and Python, but these are just *warnings*; and 2. The consistent, actual problem that the wheel you're trying to install isn't compatible with your platform (it's for Python 2.7 on 64-bit Windows, per the file name).

Comment: use easy_install.  i dont have windows but the suggestion might work

Comment: also pip may be installing packages for python2.7.  in my case i do pip3 intstall numpy.  you might need something like that

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes you are righ, but i couldn't find the wheel for `Python 3.4`, i searched online, it is available for `Python 2.7` or `Python 3.5`, can you suggest latest version of wheel for numpy and mkl which is compatible with `Python 3.4`

Comment: @RoushanSingh i have tried with easy_install, i am getting error

Comment: Presumably, like you're seeing with pip, they don't support older versions of Python with newer versions of numpy.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Actually the issue started while ruuning executable file for my application actually,i am using pyinstaller, two moths back, i have used the same command for generating executable file, it has worked fine, again after some updates in a tool, i have generated executable file using pyinstaller, i got `MKL FATAL EOOR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll` error, while running exe file, and tool has aborted.

Comment: which platform are you on. which version . windows 10?

Comment: Yes I am using windows 10

Comment: @RoushanSingh I searched for `mkl_intel_thread.dll` file in python installed directory and coppied to the folder where generated executable file is located and with the i can run the tool successfully, but i feel this is not the solution for this issue

Comment: @RoushanSingh Did you got any Updates on my Post, if so reply on the same.

Comment: @PradeepYenkuwale  The error is not deprecation  that's just the warning. The error is the wheel you have for numpy. Find a wheel that is supported on your system and install it. if you really want numpy to just work you can also try virtualenvs  maybe they will work. conda ,pipenv ,or virtualenv  you can go with any that works. Unfortunately i use linux and so am not the best candidate to solve your problem. i hope it works.

Comment: @RoushanSingh i have installed correct wheel for numpy and it is working for me and i can able to generate now executable (Compiled version) file using pyinstaller

Comment: good to hear that @PradeepYenkuwale